# Different font styling with Bootstrap Glyphicons on Azure

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, azure, glyphicons

I have created Web App using ASP .NET MVC 5, Bootstrap 3.3.6 and Glyphicons installed from Nuget. I have a problem with font styling of navigation links, only those with added Glyphicons. Problem occurs on Azure. To be clear, Glyphicons are displayed. On azure they are bigger, also following names use different fonts, which is incorrect. Any ideas..?

I had the same problem with styling on localhost, but I fixed it using below code. Added **.glyphicon:before{ }** section and changed to **.glyphicon{ font-family:inherit ;}** from 'Glyphicons Halflings'.

bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
.glyphicon {
  position:  relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon:before{
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

I have no idea why it is not working on Azure.

Rest of my code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-top:14px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" href="/Home/Index">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:14px"> Home Page</span></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Offers", "All", "Offers", null, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-road " })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>                   
    </ul>
</div>
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqueryui").Include(
                  "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"));
    }
```

Web.config

```
</system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This is how the "Offers" navigation links looks like when inspecting in IE:

[1. on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rudyE.jpg)

[2. on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17eJ2.jpg)

Glyphicons are located in **mainfolder/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.(eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2)**

All bootstrap css' are located in **mainfolder/Content/bootstrap*.(css,map)**

Comment: Do you also have `bootstrap.min.css`?  If you set `<compilation debug="false">` in web.config does the problem happen locally?

Comment: You have `less` files vs `css` files in the 2 screenshots?

Comment: @Paul Abbott - yes, I have **bootstrap.min.css** and when I set **<compilation debug="false">** the problem exists on my locaclhost. When it is set to "true" styling is ok.

Comment: @EdSF - on the second screenshot there is one more rule **.glyphicon:before** applied when rendering "Offers" navigation link on a localhost. Thanks to this code, which I have added to the **bootstrap.css**, styling is ok. It seems that this part is missing on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bundling.

When you run locally in debug mode, the `.css` files are sent individually to the browser.  When not in debug mode (when you deploy), the `.min.css` files are bundled together into one file and sent.  If there is no `.min.css` file, it gets minified on the fly.

In other words, your changes are not in `bootstrap.min.css` so your changes are not going to appear in the deployed application.  Minify `bootstrap.css` (there are plenty of online tools) and replace the contents of `bootstrap.min.css`.  Or better yet leave the bootstrap files alone (so upgrading bootsrap to newer versions is not going to be difficult) and override anything you need to in a separate css file that gets loaded last in the bundle.